# how to retrieve correct time from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $scheduledate = $_POST['Date'];
 $time = $_POST['HH'].':'.$_POST['Min'].' '.$_POST['AmPm'];
   $totalTimetoSchedule = $scheduledate.' '.$time;

  $scheduledateTime = strtotime($totalTimetoSchedule); //scheduleTime

//this time is save in my mysql table now i am fetch and show my time


date('m/d/Y h:i A',$msgdetail['schedule_dateTime'])
```

when i saved my time in schedule_dateTime field this save according to my time but when i retrieve my time in this format this return me 5 hours late time means if time is 2.20 am its return me 7.20 am how to solve this problem

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php   use that to set proper time zone for your PHP

Answer (score 0):

Simply SELECT `@@system_time_zone`;

Returns PST (or whatever is relevant to your system).

If you're trying to determine the session timezone you can use this query:

```
SELECT IF(@@session.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@session.time_zone);
```

Which will return the session timezone if it differs from the system timezone.

and in php:
You can either use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` variable

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Or:
 $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

 // This would return the date in the following formats respectively:
 $date = '2012-03-06 17:33:07';
 // Or
 $date = '2012/03/06 17:33:07';
```

Comment: date_default_timezone_set(timezone_name_from_abbr('MST')); but after that time not show correctly

Answer (score 0):

Set your country time zone by using this function `date_default_timezone_set()` on the top of the file at least before you use any `date()` function, if you have one common file like `header.php` or `config.php` better to use this function `date_default_timezone_set()` at there only one time.

You can use this function like

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome')
```

Find your country timezone from this link [timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Before you ask any question here, please search for relevant question, this question may answered few times.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set(timezone_name_from_abbr('MST')); but after that time not show correctly

Comment: @VishwaFauzdar `echo` the `$scheduledateTime` value and cross check value with DB and also `echo` the `$msgdetail['schedule_dateTime']` value before changing the format, I am sure all three values won't be equal.